# Duplicate tags: [google-cloud-workflows] and [google-workflows]

Tags: support, tags

These seem duplicative, and both relate to the Workflows product on Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/workflows.

Comment: I don't understand where you have seen the [tag:google-cloud-workflows]. It doesn't exist today on SO proper and as far as I can tell [never did](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1415168). Nor is this tag defined as synonym. There is nothing in this question that was or is actionable.

Comment: Thank you. Someone must have deleted it.  Google cache shows several postings from April: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HnlJmju7u1AJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-workflows+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Okay, I missed that I could look for posthistory records as well. I found a few of those indeed: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1415168 but the posts where those tags were added are all edited/re-tagged to remove the tag. We're all good now.